# Need help on a simple TCL script regarding regexp

Tags: regex, tcl

I'm trying to write a tcl script basically to do following. Based on the syslog below,

LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface GigabitEthernet1/0/23, changed state to down

When that log is seen on the router, the script needs to push out a shell command which includes the interface index number, in this case it is 23. I can use regex to scrape the interface in the syslog by doing this below.

```
set interface ""
if {[regexp {.* (GigabitEthernet1/0/[0-9]*)} $syslog_msg match interface]}
if [catch {cli_exec $cli1(fd) "show port_diag unit 1 port 23"} result] {
error $result $errorInfo
}
}
```

But how can I use only the interface index number (which is 23) in the command above? Do I need to extract [0-9]* from the regexp and store it as a vairable or somethig like that?

Answer (score 1):

Please just enclose the expression `[0-9]*` with parentheses and append
a variable name, say `num`, to be assigned to the second capture group.
Here is a snipped code to demonstrate:

```
if {[regexp {.* (GigabitEthernet1/0/([0-9]*))} $syslog_msg match interface num]} {
    puts $num
}
```

Output:

```
23
```

If the result looks okay, modify the command within the curly braces to perform your task as:

```
if {[regexp {.* (GigabitEthernet1/0/([0-9]*))} $syslog_msg match interface num]} {  
    if [catch {cli_exec $cli1(fd) "show port_diag unit 1 port $num"} result] {
        error $result $errorInfo
    }
}
```

Comment: The `catch` command substitution should be in braces: `if {[catch ... result]}`

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. From testing I see the catch works fine without the curly braces. However, this below does not work. It is not executing the command.              

if {[regexp {.* (GigabitEthernet1/0/([0-9]*))} $syslog_msg match interface num]} {  
    if [catch {cli_exec $cli1(fd) "show port_diag unit 1 port $num"} result] {
        error $result $errorInfo
    }
}

Comment: ::cisco::eem::event_register_syslog pattern "LINEPROTO-5-UPDOWN: Line protocol on Interface GigabitEthernet" maxrun_sec 600

# Open CLI

if [catch {cli_open} result] {
    error $result $errorInfo
} else {
    array set cli1 $result
}
if [catch {cli_exec $cli1(fd) "terminal length 0"} result] {
error $result $errorInfo
}

set port ""

if {[regexp {.* (GigabitEthernet1/0/([0-9]*)).*} $syslog_msg match port num]} {
if [catch {cli_exec $cli1(fd) "show port_diag unit 1 port $num"} result] {
error $result $errorInfo
}
}

Comment: Doing that `catch`/`error` combination looks weird. Why catch something just to let it go again immediately? All you do is lose a little bit of the extended error information (the error code, the error location, stuff like that). Usually only catch things if you're going to do something _useful_ with that!

Comment: Oh hi, the original answer works, there was just some errors in my cli syntax, after I corrected them, it works perfectly. Thank you all!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. If you consider your problem is solved with my answer (although there may be a room to improve the usage of catch), I'd appreciate if you can accept it by clicking on the check mark beside the answer. BR.